# VBA WORD - Date/time picker - long date code

Tags: vba, date, ms-word

I have created a user form and added a date/time picker control.

Date time picker is named: `CDOBtextbox` and populates a bookmark called `CDOB`

It currently populates a date as `DD MM YYYY` but I would like it to populate the bookmark as `D MMMM YYYY`.

I know there is a `3 - dtp custom` format for the date/time picker but cannot figure out how to set a custom format for the life of me.

If anyone thinks they can help and/or needs more information please ask - have been stuck looking for an answer (sorry i am new to this whole coding thing)

Comment: use the Format function: Format(DateTime.Now, "D MMMM YYYY")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CustomFormat` property of DateTime Picker is case sensitive.

---

This is wrong : `DD MM YYYY`

This is right : `dd MM yyyy`
[image]

---

In VBA

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    DTPicker1.Format = dtpCustom
    DTPicker1.CustomFormat = "dd MM yyyy"
    DTPicker1.Value = Date
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Cyboashu, can't believe i missed the customformat option in properties - have changed that format to `d MMMM yyyy` 

however, when i use the code

`Private Sub UserForm_Click()
TextBoxCDOB.Format = dtpCustom
TextBoxCDOB.CustomFormat = "d MMMM yyyy"
TextBoxCDOB.Value = Date
End Sub`

it still populates the bookmarks as `dd MM yyyy` - any suggestions?

Comment: Need to see the code which is updating the book mark from date picker.

Comment: `Private Sub CommandButtonOk_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveDocument

        Call UpdateBookmark("CDOB", TextBoxCDOB.Value)
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Unload Me
End Sub`

Comment: `Call UpdateBookmark("CDOB", Format( TextBoxCDOB.Value, "d MMM yyyy"))`

Comment: aaaaaaye you are a legend!!!!! you are now officially my bestfriend - thank you @cyboashu !!!! do i need to keep the `Private Sub UserForm_Click() TextBoxCDOB.Format ` code ???

Comment: dear friend, :) that code was just an example. you dont need it.